# SVG symbol use href (with Font Awesome, React and TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, font-awesome

### Desired Result

I'm trying to incorporate Font Awesome in our React+TypeScript SPA, and looking for an end-result similar to this:

```
<svg><symbol id="trash"><path d="..."/></symbol></svg>
...
<svg><use href="#trash"/></svg>
```

In other words, I'm trying to define the `<symbol/>` once, and then reuse (potentially many times) via `<use href="..."/>`.

### Current Result

However, this is the best I was able to do so far...

```
<svg><path d="..."/></svg>
```

...which was done by TypeScript code similar to this:

```
import { faTrash } from "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons";
...
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} />
```

This means that if I use the same icon multiple times, I'm effectively duplicating the same `<path/>` as many times.

### Rationale

*Not* embedding `<path/>` directly under `<svg/>` is very important for us for performance reasons. We are building a Windows Explorer-like UI which can display hundreds of items at a time (most with the same icon), and embedding `<path/>` (instead of indirectly referencing sprites through `<use/>`) adds several seconds to the rendering time.

### Question

So my question is: how do I reach the "Desired Result" as described above, preferably using strongly typed mechanisms that the TypeScript compiler can verify? Ideally I'd like to keep using `<FontAwesomeIcon/>` for its customization capabilities.

I noticed `<FontAwesomeIcon ... symbol/>` in the [docs](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react), but I'm unsure how I'm supposed to use it.

### Environment

Here are my package versions, if that matters:

```
@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core       1.2.36
@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons      5.15.4
@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons        5.15.4
@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons      5.15.4
@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons        5.15.4
@fortawesome/react-fontawesome          0.1.15
@types/react-dom                        17.0.9
@types/react                            17.0.29
react-dom                               17.0.2
react                                   17.0.2
typescript                              4.4.4
```

Comment: That's surprising as `<use>` clones so I'd expect `<use>` to have been slower than inline SVG.

Comment: @RobertLongson I suspect it has something to do with SVG rendering: if the browser knows that the same SVG (with same dimensions etc.) is used many times, it can (in theory) rasterize it once and then just reuse the resulting bitmap. Whether this actually happens, or there are other things at play here I'm not sure. In any case the effect is real - we measure it - and is even mentioned in the [docs](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/svg-symbols): _"You can leverage the SVG Sprites technique to make repeated icons more performant on your page."_.

Comment: Just to give some context about the performance impact that we are facing: in one test under Chrome DevTools Performance tab, loading a new page showing 500 objects took **~12 s** for "Rendering" (most of it for "Recalculating Styles") when using "embedded" SVGs (i.e. repeated `<path/>`s), which dropped to **~0.6 s** when using "indirect" SVGs (i.e. one `<path/>` with repeated `<using/>`s).